Go to last changed line when opening file
When I open a file with unstaged changes it would be ideal for me to automatically jump to to them, I currently use GitGutterNextHunk from airblade/vim-gitgutter.
Also as a bonus, I would also like to land on latest change in git history if available.
I know I need to listen to BufEnter, but does anyone use this workflow? or an alternative?
I use nvim btw

You talk about gitgutter but you tag fugitive, which is a different plugin. This is somehow puzzling me. Are you looking for fugitive-related answers or is it just an oversight?

Yeah, I added this tag because I was hoping that the solution would be something that's achievable with this plugin

Apparently, BufEnter is not what you think. Instead, it's BufRead (aka BufReadPost). The example code is under :h restore-cursor.

When I open a file with unstaged changes

I think it makes sense simply to jump to the latest change :h '. in a file instead. Of course, it's not the same thing (as some changes may be non-staged yet, or :undone) but for many uses it is an adequate choice.
